# Select distinct column names in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

My table contains several columns and I need to select distinct rows in two specific columns using Linq.

My SQL equivalent is:

```
Select distinct Level1Id, Level1Name
from levels
```

What I currently do is:

```
db.levels.GroupBy(c=> c.Level1Id).Select(s => s.First())
```

This will retrieve the whole row not only Level1Id and Level1Name. How can I specify the columns I want to retrieve in this linq query?

Comment: now, for the answers below, do I want to use variable c or l :)

Answer (score 6):

With Select, you can specify the columns in an anonymous object and then use Distinct on that:

```
  db.levels.Select(l => new{ l.Level1Id, l.Level1Name }).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 3):

try

`db.levels.Select(c => new {c.Level1Id, c.Level1Name}).Distinct();`

Answer (score 3):

Specify the two columns in your `LINQ` query select, create an anonymous object with `Level1Id` and `Level1Name` properties:

```
var query = (from v in db.levels
            select new { Level1Id = v.Level1Id, Level1Name = v.Level1Name }).Distinct();
```

and use each item like this:

```
foreach (var r in query){
  int valId = r.LevelId;
  int level = r.Level1Name;
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are so close, one more step:

```
var result = db.levels.GroupBy(c=> new { c.Level1Id, c.Level1Name })
               .Select(s => s.First())
```

The key thing is: Anonymous type uses structural comparison, that's why `GroupBy` or any other answer do work.